# Renderer2 error - id did not match any elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular-renderer2

So I have an input field which I would like to focus on load in an Angular application. I read that the Renderer2 way is the good method of doing so, and it works if I call the function for example on click like so:

```
focusMyInput() {
    this.renderer.selectRootElement('#myInput').focus();
}
```

But if I try to make it focus on load, like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.selectRootElement('#myInput').focus();
}
```

It throws an error:

```
 The selector "#myInput" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement
```

HTML:

```
<input id="myInput" />
```

Any idea what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: can you put html element anf viewchild code line too  to question ?

Comment: No ViewChild here but there's an input tag with ID, this is the article: https://onthecode.co.uk/angular-material-focus-form-input-with-renderer2/

Comment: There might be a chance that your input has not been initialized when the ngAfterViewInit has fired. May be the input is inside a block with *ngIf. Sharing your html will help.

Comment: Actually it is inside the *ngIf, this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.myInput.nativeElement)"returns that input field, but if I try to apply focus() it throws the same undefined error, longer timeout does not help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with:

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.renderer.selectRootElement('#myInput').focus());
}
```

More details on [this article](https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/).

It seems there is a long long discussion about having an event after the render. [This solution](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734#issuecomment-78202524) could be helpful or (really ugly) set a 100ms timeout in my previous proposed solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but same error remains... renderer works when I trigger it from a function, but the problem seems to be in lifecycle hooks for some reason - they do work, I can console log it, but it can't trigger the function from ngOnInit or afterViewInit

Comment: The selector "#myInput" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement ...

Comment: thanks, but same error remains :( thanks guys anyway, I will try some other stuff

Comment: ok for some reason it works now with timeout, currently with 5000ms... lol. thanks for the efforts, will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3):

Please try this [workig demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lw6e7t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
 @ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;//if it is direct child or element
 @ContentChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;// if it is inside ng-content html
    
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.myInput.nativeElement).focus();
}
```

> or

```
 ngAfterContentInit() {
this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.myInput.nativeElement).focus();
    }
```

> in Html you have to do like

```
<input id="myInput" #myInput />
```

Comment: tried it...nativeElement is undefined, but it does not work without it also

Comment: please add  #myInput  in input

Comment: Yes I did, no result

Comment: try ContentChild in place  ViewChild

Comment: please check this poc https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lw6e7t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: this "this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.myInput.nativeElement)" actually returns that input field, but if I try to apply focus() it does not work as in your example unfortunately... throws the same undefined error, I tried to wrap it in longer interval but nothing happens. thanks for your effort